# Comparing 2 win32 classes to get related information

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Ok the code is super simple but I can't seem to pull the manufacturer information. It has been about a year since I last sat scripted with powershell but it doesn't seem like it should be so difficult to get this to work.

```
$Var1 = GWMI Win32_PhysicalMedia
$Var2 = GWMI Win32_diskdrive |Select model
ForEach ($Item in $var2) {
    $Item |Select model |Where {$_.deviceID -eq $Var1.tag}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of notes: This bit:

```
$Var2 = GWMI Win32_diskdrive |Select model
ForEach ($Item in $Var2) {
 $Item |Select model |Where {$_.deviceID -eq $Var1.tag}
}
```

You're basically saying: "Give me the "model" property of the win32_diskdrive(s), and then later you want to filter on the "deviceId" property (which you don't have because you selected only model).

Also, you're assuming $var1 is an object, not an array of objects (which it very well could be). If you want to iterate each of the items in $var2 and compare it to each of the objects in $var1 and see if you have a match, I would put another loop inside your loop (note that there are other ways to search arrays besides this):

```
 $Var1 = GWMI Win32_PhysicalMedia
 $Var2 = GWMI Win32_diskdrive
 #Iterate through each item in $var2
 ForEach ($Item in $Var2) {
     #Iterate through each item in $var1
     foreach ($var1item in $var1)
         {
             #look for a match
             $founditem = $Item |Where {$_.deviceID.tostring() -eq $var1item.tag.tostring()}
             if ($founditem)
                 {
                     #if match, return the object
                     $FoundItem        
                 }

         }

 }
```

I would advise you to spend some time debugging these types of problems by looking at the objects PowerShell returns with .Gettype() and | get-member. Understanding the objects you work with is key to understanding PowerShell.

Comment: hmm this seemed to have worked o.0 I didn't think about creating another look as it seemed that the where command would of done that for me o.0... also the I didn't mean to add the "| model|" in there, i didn't have it in the code I was testing.

Answer (score 0):

In your foreach loop, the variable name you are calling is $var2 not $Var2 as you used earlier. I made the change on my system and  it worked.

```
$Var1 = GWMI Win32_PhysicalMedia
$Var2 = GWMI Win32_diskdrive |Select model
ForEach ($Item in $Var2) {
    $Item |Select model |Where {$_.deviceID -eq $Var1.tag}
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: still a no-go. Just got home from work so gunna keep playing with it until i get it >.>

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want

```
$drives = gwmi win32_diskdrive
$media = gwmi Win32_PhysicalMedia
foreach ($d in $drives) { 
  $media | where {$_.tag -eq $d.deviceID} | select <comma-separated list of properties>
}
```

or just

```
gwmi win32_diskdrive | select deviceID, model | ft -auto
```

Or what manufacturer information are you looking for exactly?